# MySQL insert statement odd behaviour

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I am trying to write insert a row into a database with a column that is a composite of other columns to help with searching. Here is my PHP code:

```
    $compose=$house." ".$street." ".$district." ".$posttown." ".$county." ".$postcode;
$sql=sprintf("INSERT INTO Address (House,Street,District,PostTown,County,PostCode,Active,Composite) VALUES ('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s',%s,'%s')",
$house,
$street,
$district,
$posttown,  
$county,
$postcode,
$binactive,
$compose);
```

(I know I should be using prepared statements, that is part of the next refactoring)

The statement executes without errors but the Composite column is being evaluated as a number. That is, if $house starts with a number that number is inserted, if $house is a name then 0 is inserted.

$compose is being concatenated properly.

The column is definitely a varchar. Here is the table create script:

```
CREATE TABLE `Address` (
`idAddress` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`House` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`Street` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`District` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`PostTown` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`County` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`PostCode` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`Composite` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
`Active` binary(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
PRIMARY KEY (`idAddress`),
UNIQUE KEY `idAddress_UNIQUE` (`idAddress`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=46 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

So...where am I going wrong?

Comment: Can you provide output of `echo $sql;`?

Comment: INSERT INTO Address (House,Street,District,PostTown,County,PostCode,Active,Composite) VALUES ('22','High Street','Somewhere','Sometown','Here','AA1 BB2',1,'22 High Street Somewhere Sometown Here AA1 BB2')

Comment: Since insert looks fine, I'd start investigating the code or method that you use to pull the data out. It might be that there's a silly bug there.

Comment: I'm inspecting the data in mysql workbench as well as with a select statement. They both show the same behaviour which says to me it is the insert that is going wrong. And I have just pasted that insert statement generated by code into workbench and guess what...same result.

Comment: can you replace **double quotes** with **single quotes** from **$compose**

Comment: I'll give that a try Satender, not sure what difference it will make. I'm away from my desk for a few hours. I'll let you know later.

Comment: I ran the `create table` statement, then I ran the `insert` statement you provided. What I get is what you expected to get. The only thing is that your `Active` column is at the end and it's defined as `binary` so it's `1` or `0`. I don't know how you end up having `Composite` column as `1` or `0`, I don't think there's a bug in the code or MySQL. Do you have any triggers defined on your table?

Comment: You got it Michael! Many thanks. I was planning to update the composite with a trigger and half wrote it the last time I looked at this code in July. Now I feel dumb ;)